# unable to assign array values to textbox

Tags: javascript

I am writing javascript that splits an array based on delimiter(,) and puts that value to  text box. Each array contains exact five comma separated values. I tried the below code and getting error

> "Error: Object doesn't support this property or method".

I found the information related to this error in this web site but it appears that it is not applicable to this context. Please anyone help me in fixing this issue.

```
<script>

function show() {
        var mycars = new Array();
        mycars[0] = "768,232,574,768.234";
        mycars[1]  = "abc, def, ghi, jkl,mno";

        for(var i=0; i<mycars[i].length; i++){
            mycars= mycars.split(",");

            document.getElementById('name')[0].value=mycars;
        }

    }
</script>
<form>
    <table class="cmn-table" id="t1" border="1"
        style="margin-left: 0.2em; margin-right: 0em">
        <tr>
            <th>Sl.No</th>
            <th>IP</th>
            <th>DP</th>
            <th>TCP</th>
            <th>SD</th>
            <th>ED</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="name11" id="s1" value="1" size="2"
                readonly="readonly" /></td>

            <td><input type="text" name="name0" id="name" size="20">
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" size="20">
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name2" id="name2" size="20">
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name3" id="name3" size="15">
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name4" id="name4" size="15">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="name0" id="s2" size="2" value="2"
                readonly="readonly" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name5" size="20">
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name1" id="name6" size="20">
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name2" id="name7" size="20">
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name3" id="name8" size="15">
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name4" id="name9" size="15">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="show()">
```

Comment: `getElementById()` returns one result. There's no need fr the array subscript.

Comment: You're attempting to overwrite your array here `mycars= mycars.split(",");`

Comment: Are you trying to split the comma delimited string over the text inputs of each row?

Comment: @j08691  Yes to your question

Comment: I read the website before posting the question and tried my best to explain. Technically I may wrong and this is the reason I am here. May I know the reason for -ve mark for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make one small change to your HTML (change the id of "name" to "name0") and use this JavaScript:

```
function show() {
    var mycars = new Array();
    var counter = 0;
    mycars[0] = "768,232,574,768,234";
    mycars[1] = "abc, def, ghi, jkl,mno";
    for (var i = 0; i < mycars.length; i++) {
        foo = mycars[i].split(",");
        for (var j = 0; j < foo.length; j++) {
            document.getElementById('name' + counter).value = foo[j];
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MB4ee/1)**

Note that I'm assuming you have a typo in your example here `mycars[0] = "768,232,574,768.234";` and that it should be `mycars[0] = "768,232,574,768,234";`